# Add job search to the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, jobs

It will be very nice to add job search feature in iOS app or do another standalone app for that like "linkedIn jobs".

Comment: **For close voters: not off topic. iOS (and android) app questions belong here on MSE.**